# ExtJs how can i catch Tab key press event in keyup in grid column editor?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, keyup

I want to check what kind of key pressed(TAB key) on grid cell. I added keyup Listener to gird column editor as bellow

```
col = grid.getColumnModel().getColumnById('my_column_id');

    col.editor.addListener('keyup', myfunc.createDelegate(this, [col.editor, arg2, arg3] ));

    myfunc= function(col.editor, arg2, arg3) {

      //if TAB press
      if(keyprss == 'TAB'){
        alert('tab');
      }
    }
```

please how can i catch tab key press in my method instead of `if(keyprss == 'TAB')`

Note: I want to answer with out remove col.editor, arg2, arg3 param in the myfunc function

Comment: is it possible for you to provide some thing more, i mean your code.
i am not able to understand "col"...

Comment: col = grid.getColumnModel().getColumnById('my_column_id'); sorry for mistake